# Reading a large number of GeoJSON files from a website using R

Tags: r, geojson, sf

I am trying to get the position of every The Things Network gateway, and the information is scattered in an awful lot of GeoJSON files (around 100,000). I've managed to get an URL of every single file with rvest but the problem comes when reading all these files. I've tried a normal map but it crashed after about a couple of hours when it encountered an URL it couldn't and had done only a few hundreds of files. Right now I'm using this code but it hasn't finished after three hours. Is there any more efficient way to tackle this problem?

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytable)
library(data.table)
library(rvest)
library(furrr)
future::multicore()

# function to read the data and handle errors
posread <- possibly(.f = st_read, otherwise = NA)

# sample data, the real table looks like this
geojson <- c("https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A0027FFFE00000F/circles.geojson", 
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A555A0000000006/circles.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A84041FFFF1EE1B/circles.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A840411BD4D4477/circle-single.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A840411BD4D4477/radar.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A840411D9AF4002/circles.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A840411D9F08415/circles.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A840411D18AC410/circles.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A840411EA1DC40A/circles.geojson",
"https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/0A840411F46D4415/circles.geojson")

jsons <- data.table(geojson)

geos <- jsons %>% 
  mutate.("file" = future_map(geojson, posread) # read
```

Comment: Normally if data is arranged like that its because the supplier doesn't want you to scrape it. Where did you get the list of 100,000 URLs from? I've managed to get 10,398 "gateway" records from a single web request with some IDs, lat-long, last_heard etc. No idea if that's also the data you want though because this is the first I've heard of this project...

Comment: The data are here https://ttnmapper.org/geojson/. In the project docs it states that data is under a PDDL license so I'd be free to use it. My guess is that it's like this because every user uploads the information about their own device. In any case there are a couple CSV files but they all refer to devices in the same city/region. How did you make your request?

Comment: https://ttnmapper.org/webapi/gwall_ttnv3.php any use?